# Converting to Type rsa.PublicKey

Tags: go

I'm trying to import my own RSA public key as opposed to generating one to encrypt a string with. Only thing is that I'm having issues changing to the correct type. Here's my current code:

```
func main() {
    s := ""
    i := new(big.Int)
    i.SetString(s, 16)

    encrypt(i)
}

func encrypt(i *big.Int) {
    publicKey := PublicKey{N: i, E: 010001}

    secretMessage := "This is super secret message!"

    encryptedMessage := RSA_OAEP_Encrypt(secretMessage, publicKey)

    fmt.Println("Cipher Text:", encryptedMessage)
}

Where it doesn't like publicKey's type

What I'm wondering is if there's a way that I can **convert type PublicKey** to **type rsa.PublicKey** so that I can use it for encryption.
```

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow need to be self contained, Joakim. Please included the code by hitting [edit] above. A [MCVE] is recommended, but at least include the code that contains the problem and full error descriptions.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of that. I've changed it now to hopefully fit the guidelines better.

Comment: Welcome to SO, question seems fine now :) Never mind downvotes on SO too much, they happen... Not so familiar with Go, but my gut instinct says that you might want to use `publicKey := rsa.PublicKey{N: i, E: 010001}` where you indicate the precise type.

Comment: Oh thank you that worked! Can't believe it was as simple as that :)

Comment: That only appears to work. In reality you won't be able to decrypt anything. That's because your modulus is really a fragment of a DER-encoded SubjectPublicKeyInfo formatted public key.

Comment: actually, on second look, your modulus appears to be even. Unless this some kind of challenge problem/CTF, you have a corrupted SPKI blob.

Comment: The public key value is also incorrect. `010001` should be hexadecimals, and the `0` in front of it won't auto-convert it to hex. But hey, one step at a time :)

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Uh, `s` ends with a 3 and since the base of hexadecimals is even, I assume that the result is odd???

Comment: s is a *fragment* of an SPKI blob. That 3 is actually part of the encoding of the public exponent, and the last bytes should actually be 0x0203010001. The last byte of the modulus is 0xfa.

Comment: Hmm, the modulus and public exponent were provided to me as such. What is it I have to do to with them to make them valid?

Comment: OK, final hint, the modulus starts ~ with `C9` and is preceded with a standard size indicator + 1 for the signed integer encoding.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two types of key: one is the base interface, called just `PublicKey`. The type `rsa.PublicKey` is derived from that and should be used instead. Otherwise the key type is not set correctly and the code will fail. I presume it creates an anonymous type with the values set.

Comment: See the comment section under the question for more things that may not be correct; this just fixes the mentioned problem.

Comment: What's funny is if you prepend 0x3082012230 and append 0x010001 you get a legit looking SPKI blob, except the modulus has several easy to find factors include 2.